# Does Tyria have Maid Droids too?

Tags: ar-tonelico

Both Shurelia and Frelia have similar looking Maid Droids like Meimei and Kanade (AKA Child of Light) for Shurelia and has Riki and Reki for Frelia.

But looking at Tyria who is the third Reyvateil Origin i don't recall see a pair of Maid Droids for her. Who are her Maid Droids? or if she doesn't have any, why doesn't she when the other 2 do?

Answer (score 1):

The Third Tower has no maintenance droids, as they were rendered obsolete with the creation and deployment of the two Harvestasya AIs, as they do the same functions that the maintenance droids do in the other Towers.